# When we select todays date time is not showing

Tags: javascript

When we select  todays date time is not showing. if we select the next days date the below mentioned times are showing.  When we select  todays date time is not showing. if we select the next days date the below mentioned times are showing.

```
var todaydate = new Date();
let yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
  minDate: yesterday
});
var old_data = '';
var current_date = '{{date("m/d/Y")}}';
var time = "{{date('h a')}}";
$(".datepicker").change(function() {
  var selected_date = $(this).val();
  if (selected_date != old_data) {
    old_data = selected_date;
    if (current_date == selected_date) {
      var html_data = '<option value="">Select Time</option>';

      if (time <= '01 pm') {
        html_data += '<option value="9am - 2pm">9am - 2pm</option>';
      }
      if (time <= '05 pm') {
        html_data += '<option value="2pm - 6pm">2pm - 6pm</option>';
      }
      if (time <= '08 pm') {
        html_data += '<option value="6pm - 11pm">6pm - 9pm</option>';
      }
    } else {
      var html_data = '<option value="">Select Time</option>' +
        '<option value="9am - 2pm">9am - 2pm</option>' +
        '<option value="2pm - 6pm">2pm - 6pm</option>' +
        '<option value="6pm - 11pm">6pm - 11pm</option>';
      $(".delivery_time").html(html_data);
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. Most code editors even do this for you. If you do that you will see immediately that `$(".delivery_time").html(html_data);` is only inside the `else` block.

Comment: is it `$('#datepicker')` or `$('.datepicker')` ?